# How to send work items through release pipeline after deployment azure devops

Tags: azure, devops

How to send  work items through release pipeline after deployment completed in azure devops

I try to use send email task but there is no option

Answer (score 0):

You can link Work Items to your pipeline like below:-

I went to my Release pipeline and Options > Integrations> Report Deployment Status to work and Report Deployment Status to Boards refer below:-

[image]

I did one commit in my existing pipeline repo and linked a Work Item to it like below:-

[image]

The Pipeline started running after the commit and the task was added to the work item like below:-

[image]

Work Item:-

[image]

Now, I triggered a release pipeline for the same and checked if the work items are included like below:-

[image]

After the release is complete click on 3 dots like below and select Send Email

[image]

***Now, As this Work item is included in the build, I send it via Email, You can enable Email notifications at the Organizational level and Project Level both.***

Project Level > Project > Project settings > Notifications > New subscriptions > Build > A Build completes >

[image]

You can also create a notification for Release refer to below:-

[image]

[image]

I received an Email after the successful build and release with the associate artifact like the one below:-

[image]

You can enable this Email Notification at the Organizational level too.

Additionally while running pipelines, You can follow the steps below:-

[image]

[image]

***Reference:-***

[Configure pipelines to support integration - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/configure-pipelines-work-tracking?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic-release#automatically-link-work-items-to-builds-or-releases)